# Populate textbox based on selected radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, radio-button

I have 3 radio buttons, when one of them is selected I want to automatically put text in a textbox.
For example, If the user selected the 'TBA' radio button, I want the text 'To Be Advised' put in the textbox, and if they select another radio button I want it to be cleared.

Can anyone help me??

http://jsfiddle.net/ej2hf/1/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this then**

http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/KNct8/

```
$('input[name="dest_type"]').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).val() == "tba"){
        $('input[type="text"]').val($(this).val());
    }
    else
    {
        $('input[type="text"]').val('');
    }

});
```

​

OR

http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/KNct8/1/

```
$('input[name="dest_type"]').on('change', function() {
     if($(this).val() == "tba"){
    $('input[type="text"]').val('To Be Advised');
    }
    else
    {
      $('input[type="text"]').val('');
    }

});​
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The second example was exactly what I was after. I just needed to add "$(document).ready(function(){" at the top. Its on a jQuery mobile app if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
$('input[name="dest_type"]').on('change', function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').val($(this).val());
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ej2hf/2/

Comment: Hi again Kane  :)   That works well, but I only need it to display text when the tba button is selected.  Something like "If radio button value = tba, then put 'To Be Advised' in textbox.

Comment: I have done the same thing please see my answer @Jamesil   :)

Comment: @Jamesil, ah? i guess i missed that part.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to populate the textbox with the value which is selected by default on page load use the below code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[type="text"]').val($('input[name="dest_type"]').val());
$('input[name="dest_type"]').on('change', function() {     
$('input[type="text"]').val ($(this).val()); }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are or can use the latest [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you can use this:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="dest_type"]').on("change", function() {
        $('input[type="text"]').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

See the [Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/DHGhk/)

---

If what you need if to toggle the value of TBA, use this:

```
$(function() {
  $('input[name="dest_type"]').on("change", function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').val( (($(this).val()=='tba')?($(this).val()):('')) );
  });
});
```

See this [Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/DHGhk/2/)

---

If none of this is what you are trying to do, please rephrase the question or add some more information!

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('input:radio[name="dest_type"]').change(function () {
   $("input:text").val($(this).val());
});
})
```